# complex maven project dependencies being compiled multiple times

Tags: java, maven

```
<project (...)>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>our.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent.of.all</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <modules>
        <module>module-common</module>
        <module>module-A</module>
        <module>module-B</module>
        <module>module-C</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                (... - some external dependecies...)
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                (... - some external dependecies...)
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                (... - some external dependecies...)
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>our.group.id</groupId>
                <artifactId>module-common</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>our.group.id</groupId>
                <artifactId>module-A</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>our.group.id</groupId>
                <artifactId>module-B</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>our.group.id</groupId>
                <artifactId>module-C</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

This is the main pom of project, that holds within some modules `module-common` `module-A` `module-B` `module-C`.

The issue that I am facing is the fact, that most of them is bing compiled and tested multiple times, because of internal dependencies between modules:

```
<project (...)>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>our.group.id</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent.of.all</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>module-B</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            (... - some external dependecies...)
        </dependency>

        <dependency> <!-- internal dependency to other module -->
            <groupId>our.group.id</groupId>
            <artifactId>module-common</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The more dependencies there are, the longer it takes to build project. How can I prevent maven from doing full install on the same modules being done multiple times?

Comment: How are you calling Maven? `mvn install`? From the root of your multi module build?

Comment: I don't think the installation of the same module will be done several times. What brings you to that conclusion? Furthermore you can just use `mvn package` instead of `mvn install`..

Comment: are you calling clean ? if you execute mvn clean install on the root project it will delete all target folders and rebuild everything. Perhaps you should try just doing mvn install or building just the modules you've changed instead of the whole project

Comment: @khmarbaise maybe information that I provided isn't full enough to get such conclusion, but that's the truth. Console output clearly states that some modules are installed multiple times. Someone wrote an answer about `-pl module-common, module-A, module-B, module-C` parameter... It works, but how can such behaviour be embeded into pom, to gain the same with simple `install`?

Comment: @dantuch Can you post a full log output of the maven run which shows the behaviour furthermore best is to post the full pom.xml files and it's structure (may be on github) so it's possible to take a look into. Apart from that if `mvn -pl ... ` will help to prevent the behaviour there is something weird in your pom files etc.

Comment: @khmarbaise ok, I'll if I find some time to prapare a new project that will behave as our production tool.